# I am used to modify a sentence

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

> I am used to modify a sentence.
> I can be used between two letters, and I can be used to swap two letters.
> My prefix is commonly used, and my suffix is sometimes found in remote places.

What am I?  One word.

There are 5 clues above; there should be 5 explanations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are a

> Commute

*I am used to modify a sentence.*

> A judge can commute a sentence.

*I can be used between two letters, and I can be used to swap two letters.*

> You can commute from A to B or you can use the [Commutative Property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) in math.

*My prefix is commonly used,*

> **Com** is short for common.

*and my suffix is sometimes found in remote places.*

> The **mute** button is found on a remote control.

Answer (score 3):

It might be a long shot, but is it possible that the word is

> **rule**?

*I am used to modify a sentence.*

> In law, a rule is defined as an order made by a judge to modify a sentence

*I can be used between two letters, and I can be used to swap two letters.*

> These are similar in that they could refer to math. You can use a rule between two letters (ie variables): `a > b`. In a similar way, you can use a rule to swap two letters: `a = b`. *While I naturally considered math/programming rather than regular English, seeing that you're a mathematician from your profile further influenced my decision to stick to this meaning.*

*My prefix is commonly used*

> A bit of a long shot but the most common use for the prefix (RUL) is within the medical field, meaning Right Upper Lobe [of a lung]. Our lungs are pretty commonly used, I'd say.

*my suffix is sometimes found in remote places.*

> Again, unlikely, but a Ule is a type of tree that can be found in rainforests of Mexico, Central America, and northern South America. A rainforest is more often than not considered remote, as it is far from civilization and difficult to get to.

Comment: It's not my intended answer.  The first and second explanations have things in common with my intended answer, though.